# Categorical reason why $\textbf{hTop}$ preserves products

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

By $\textbf{hTop}$, I mean the [naive homotopy category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category#The_naive_homotopy_category).

Topologically speaking, it follows because homotopies into spaces assemble into a homotopy into the product space, but is there a categorical reason for why this is true? Is the canonical functor $F: \textbf{Top} \rightarrow \textbf{hTop}$ representable or is there a class of quotient categories that preserve limits or something along those lines?

I've tried to leverage the bijectiveness and fullness of $F$, but didn't get far without faithfulness.

Comment: Would an explanation using  [monoidal model categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+model+category) be satisfactory? I think one might have to restrict to “good spaces” for this

Comment: How do you define $hTop$? (there are several)

Comment: @Tyrone Can you give an answer for a suitable interpretation?

Comment: I suppose it all comes down to the fact that the path components functor preserves products (for nice spaces). It doesn't preserve equalisers, however.

Comment: @Tyrone  I'm quite new to AT and CT, I've updated the question.

Comment: @Andres Mejia Thank you for the input, but I'm afraid that's way over my head. I might just be overestimating basic category theory when it comes to handling specific cases like this.

Comment: No problem. I was just trying to think of something. By the way, [most limits are not preserved](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120534/basic-questions-on-the-homotopy-category)